# Mobile View is super zoomed out (link included)

Tags: html, css, web, responsive

I have made my website mostly responsive for desktop browsers. However, when I open it on mobile it is super zoomed out, despite having the meta viewport on :(

any ideas?

https://mickadamouse1.github.io/Portfolio/

here's a link to my website so far^^

can't add any screenshots because I need "10 reputation to post images".

Comment: Looks good to me, can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Same here... is your zoom set to 100%?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the type of quotation marks you're using here:

```
    <meta name=”viewport” content=”width=device-width, initial-scale=5″>
```

They look like the curly ones from MS Word, not regular " ", and that often causes problems.

Edit: Also change the initial-scale value to 1 maybe?

Comment: That fixed it! I'd have never guessed that to cause a problem :3 thank you so much <3

Comment: Glad I could help, I've gotten caught up by little things like that myself =)

Answer (score 0):

try using this viewport meta tag
`<meta content='width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1' name='viewport'>`